# Javascript void(0) not working

Tags: javascript

I'm making a chat site and I wanted to make a JavaScript hyperlink that makes the send button to chat unpushable. So in my chat I can make hyperlinks by [url=http://www.site.com]text[/url]. But javascript still works in them. The code is: `javascript:document.getElementById("sendbutton").disabled = true; void(0)`. So I test this code out in my address bar and it succeds in doing the command and it dosent change the page. But when I put it im my hyperlink and click it, it will load a blank white page with the word "disabled" on top. What did I do wrong? Why is the void(0) command working in my address bar but not when put in a hyperlink?

Comment: Please, **never** describe something as "not working" its just a piss poor method of describing a problem that begs for more detail.

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you've tried and why it might not be working.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the anchor tag from performing its default action (changing the document location) you have to cancel its `onclick` event like this:

```
<a href="..." onclick="return false;">do it</a>
```

This way no matter what is the `href` of the anchor, it won't redirect the page.

However, it will also cancel any JavaScript code you have already as the `href` so you need to perform it all in the `onclick` event itself:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('sendbutton').disabled = true; void(0); return false;">do it</a>
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/qnCKW/).

Comment: please make href='', else it will append ... at the end of query string of current page.

Comment: @Mohit good point - see my edit.

Comment: @Shadow_Wizard nice sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the **jQuery** click callback.

```
$("#sendbutton").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Should stop the page reloading.
}
```

Note that by returning `false` from this callback is equivalent to  calling `preventDefault()` and `stopPropogation()`

Comment: jQuery is not magic potion - you don't need it for every tiny thing. Looks like the OP doesn't use it yet and for such minor thing it's not really worth using it.

Comment: It's still a valid alternative, and chances are that other people might end up here looking for **solutions** to the same problem, not JS purism, and find this helpful.